# Reading tsv files with byte strings with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a tsv file with a column containing utf-8 encoded byte strings (e.g., `b'La croisi\xc3\xa8re'`). I am trying to read this file with the `pandas` method `read_csv`, but what I get is a column of strings, not byte strings (e.g., `"b'La croisi\xc3\xa8re'"`).

How can I read that column as byte strings instead of regular strings in Python 3? I tried to use `dtype={'my_bytestr_col': bytes}` in `read_csv` with no luck.

Another way to put it: How can I go from something like `"b'La croisi\xc3\xa8re'"` to `b'La croisi\xc3\xa8re'`?

Comment: to go from something like `"b'La croisi\xc3\xa8re'"` to `b'La croisi\xc3\xa8re'` you can do `data[2:-1].encode()`

Comment: Not really, this returns the following wrongly encoded byte string: `b'La croisi\xc3\x83\xc2\xa8re'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample file:

```
    First Name  Last Name   bytes
0   foo          bar        b'La croisi\xc3\xa8re'
```

then try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
df = pd.read_csv('file.tsv', sep='\t')
df['bytes'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Out:

```
0    b'La croisi\xc3\xa8re'
Name: bytes, dtype: object
```

Comment: This doesn't work because it opens the utf-8 encoded byte string column from my `tsv` file into a simple string. Maybe there's a set of arguments I could pass to this function that would fix it?

Comment: bytes(str(df['my_bytestr_col']),'utf-8')

Comment: This returns `b"b'La croisi\\xc3\\xa8re'"` in Python 3

Comment: OK, this should work for you: df['bytes'].apply(ast.literal_eval)